# Where do I add a Typescript type definition within an Ember CLI app?

Tags: typescript, ember-cli, glimmer.js

I already

```
ember -v
ember-cli: 3.0.4
yarn add typescript -D
ember install ember-cli-typescript@latest
```

I changed the extension of some files from js to ts. Everything works ;D

I haven't been able to find an example for adding a new type. Possibly a matter of not knowing the correct search keywords that I should use.

So, if I have:

```
const myMar: Foobar = this.get('thePropOfTypeFoobar')
```

Where do I define the type `Foobar`? Is it a file I have to create somewhere?

Comment: Is it a global type? Couldn't you just add it in the same place where it's used?

Comment: Yeah, for the whole app, global.